# Have one element fade in on top of the other one with Framer Motion

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am trying to fade out one div in the same space as I am trying to fade another div in using Framer Motion. Even with a delay on the transition, the object itself renders immediately which causes the other object in the same space to jump around.

Here is a small code example of what I'm trying to do:

```
  const [short, setShort] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <img src="image.jpg" />
      <AnimatePresence>
        {!short && (
          <motion.span
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ delay: 1.5 }}
            key="logoText"
          >
            TEXT
          </motion.span>
        )}
        {short && (
          <motion.span
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{delay: 1.5}}
            key="searchBox"
          >
            SOME DIFFERENT TEXT
          </motion.span>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>

      <Button onClick={() => setShort(!short)}>Toggle</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Essentially the space taken up by `SOME DIFFERENT TEXT` instantly appears, pushing the Toggle button out to the right, and then pushes in once `TEXT` has disappeared. And then `SOME DIFFERENT TEXT` is pushed out again to the right as soon as the button is clicked.

How can I get both items to take up the same space, so they seamlessly transition into each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `exitBeforeEnter` prop (https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#animatepresenceprops.exitbeforeenter) to the `AnimatePresence` component, which will ensure `TEXT` is fully removed before `SOME DIFFERENT TEXT` appears